# Assigned independent axis cannot be used. This may be due to an unset Orientation property for the axis.in wpf chart c#

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, wpftoolkit

I want implement rotation and interval of axis label on x axis with LinearAxis in code behind.

```
lineSeria = new LineSeries();
linAxis = new LinearAxis();
linAxis.Orientation = AxisOrientation.X;
linAxis.Location = AxisLocation.Bottom;
linAxis.Interval = 10;    

var xLabel = new Style(typeof(AxisLabel));
var rotation = new Setter(AxisLabel.RenderTransformProperty, 
                          new RotateTransform() 
                              { 
                                  Angle = -90, 
                                  CenterX = 50, 
                                  CenterY = 1 
                              }
                          );

xLabel.Setters.Add(rotation);
linAxis.AxisLabelStyle = xLabel;

lineSeria.ItemsSource = drowMap[zoomedPointElem.Key];
lineSeria.DependentValuePath = "Value";
lineSeria.IndependentValuePath = "Key";
lineSeria.IndependentAxis = linAxis;
chart[coefficient].Series.Add(lineSeria);
```

I did this way but something i missed, got this problem  "Assigned independent axis cannot be used. This may be due to an unset Orientation property for the axis." How can i fix it, need code behind please. Thank you

Comment: I tested your code and it worked without errors. I think that your error is located in some other place. Also check the `chart[coefficient].ActualAxes` property, if it has existing axes, use it instead of creating a new one, like this: `var linAxis = (LinearAxis)this.lineChart1.ActualAxes.First(a => a.Orientation == AxisOrientation.X);`

Comment: Also it may be because the `Key` property is not a number.

Comment: Yes you're right, IndependentValuePath takes Key from Queue which are strings. What I should do for strings? Thank you

Comment: If these strings look like numbers, use `int.Parse`. If these strings do not ressemble numbers at all, then replace `LinerAxis` by `CategoryAxis`

Comment: I used CategoryAxis but it doesn't have Interval like LinearAxis does. I need to implement Interval, how can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had this error because your keys were not numbers, and in order to use `LinearAxis` you should convert your strings to numbers.

At first create a new class for chart items:

```
public class ChartItemModel 
{
    public double Key { get; set; }

    public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then add a method for converting your original collection to the collection of `ChartItemModel`:

```
private List<ChartItemModel> MapChartItemsList(Dictionary<string, double> drawMap) 
{
    return drawMap.Select(kv => MapChartItem(kv)).ToList();
}

private ChartItemModel MapChartItem(KeyValuePair<string, double> kv) 
{
    var model = new ChartItemModel();
    model.Key = double.Parse(kv.Key);
    model.Value = kv.Value;

    return model;
}
```

Then change your code where you set `lineSeria.ItemsSource = drowMap[zoomedPointElem.Key];`, use the next code instead:

```
lineSeria.ItemsSource = MapChartItemsList(drowMap[zoomedPointElem.Key]);
```

My code above is just an example and it may not work in your application. But the concept is the same, all that you should do is to rewrite the `MapChartItemsList` method according to your data.

Comment: One more thing i should told you, that strings are for example "12:12:14.5" and i must show them in this format. Becouse of that in the line you gave me  model.Key = long.Parse(kv.Key), it throws error "Input string was not in a correct format." He can't parse it. Is there any way?

Comment: @Sejn And what do these ':' colons mean? Such string can't be parsed as a number. So use `CategoryAxis` if you can't convert such string to a number.

Comment: It is shows time so it has ':' charaters. Because of that if they are many of them on x axis i must insert Interval for better visibility and CategoryAxis doesn't have it. Don't know what to do...

Comment: @Sejn 1) use `var time = TimeSpan.Parse(str)`; 2) use `time .TotalMilliseconds` property for the `Key` value. Also I would reccomend you to use `DateTimeAxis`, it is better for your time values than linear axis.

Comment: Can not parse string with TimeSpan because they are big numbers. Do you know some other way for implementation string to LinearAxis?

Comment: @Sejn How can they be big numbers if you said that these strings represented time? And "12:12:14.5" can be easily parsed.

Comment: @Sejn Anyway there should be a way to convert non-standard time to a normal time. I don't know what 30456 means, but I think it could be converted to some real date by using some calculations.